# Adding an account ID to an ECR image repository permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using the aws CLI I'm trying to find a way to add an account ID to an ecr image repositories permissions without having to rewrite the whole json. is there an easy way to do this?

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowCrossAccountPull",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::111:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::222:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::333:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::444:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::<ADD_NEW_ACCOUNT_HERE>:root",
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
        "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:ListImages",
        "ecr:ListTagsForResource"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify, adding how? In CloudFormation, terraform?

Comment: with aws cli  ideally

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to achieve or what you tried?